# Send data from one activity to another

Tags: java, android-studio

I want sent the content of the variable indicatorpositionstart of main2Activity to mainActivity. I used the solution "extra", but does not work.

What's the problem?

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button imageValidate;
int indicatorPositionStart = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

imageValidate = findViewById(R.id.buttonValidate);

imageValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent2.putExtra("indicatorPositionStartt", indicatorPositionStart );
startActivity(intent2);
}
});

}

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

int id = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

if (id != 0) {
int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("indicatorPositionStartt", 0);
String indicatorPositionStart = String.valueOf(id);

textView.setText(indicatorPositionStart);
}
}

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you use the string "indicatorPositionStartt" with an extra "t" at the end twice - is this a typo?

Comment: No i use to differentiate the variable and the key extra.

Comment: What do you mean by it "does not work"? What happens when you run your app? Does it crash? If so, what is the stacktrace? If not, what happens?

Comment: The app crashes but not back on android studio. Communication analyzer this ?

Comment: The application opens and closes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are checking the value before you get them from the extras, see this lines on the second activity:

```
// you are using it here, before getting the value
if (id != 0) {
int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("indicatorPositionStartt", 0);
String indicatorPositionStart = String.valueOf(id);

textView.setText(indicatorPositionStart);
}
}
```

Another problem on the `MainActivity` is that you are not filling in the id field.
I fixed it, just replace this one with your second activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    int id = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    // get the value first
    id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("indicatorPositionStartt", 0);

    // then use it
    if (id != 0) {
        String indicatorPositionStart = String.valueOf(id);
        textView.setText(indicatorPositionStart);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem is, MainActivity it's the starter of the application. And so getExtra does not exist at this time.

Comment: Humm, ok. Maybe you should analyze your app navigation logic.

Comment: I open activity one, 
then the activity two, then activity two which when I press a button returns activity 1 a variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, remove this check `if (id !=0 )` because activity started you set the value of `id =0` so  `if (id !=0 )` this if is never true.

For Sending Data:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class); 
intent.putExtra("arg", YourData); 
startActivity(intent);
```

For Receiving Data:

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("arg");
```

**Update**

remove `if( id != 0)` and use `if(getIntent().hasExtra("indicatorPositionStartt"))`

like this:

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("indicatorPositionStartt")) {
int id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("indicatorPositionStartt", 0);
String indicatorPositionStart = String.valueOf(id);

textView.setText(indicatorPositionStart);
}
```

Comment: I have not used this?

Comment: check your if condition. if ( id != 0) alway false. So you never get enter in if condition and never get value from intent.

Comment: Yes because I start with MainActivity. If not, look for getExtra which does not exist.

Comment: The solution  try {
            id = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("indicatorPositionStartt");
            String indicatorPositionStart = String.valueOf(id);
            textView.setText(indicatorPositionStart);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }

Comment: great. But before getting value from intent, check intent value exist or not by using hasExtra method. So you don't need to use try and catch block